# Validation all or none Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am working on a project i have 3 FormControls and i need to validate them in such a way that either all of them have values selected or none of them, otherwise they are not valid. How to do this kind of Validations ?

Comment: Read up on this. https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/03/14/custom-validators-in-angular-2.html

Comment: Try something out first, and go back to this site if you encounter any problem.

Comment: @BkSantiago not able to figure out how to apply this validation, when submit button is pressed

Comment: The link above has example on it, try it first, once you encounter a problem, post your code here, both `html` and component `ts`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what you probably want is to create a validation that applies not to single fields but to a `FormGroup` in an Angular reactive form.

Say you have a form like this:

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
  firstname: '',
  surname: '',
  age: '',
  address: this.fb.group({
    street: '',
    zipCode: ''
  }, { validator: addressRequired })
});
```

..then you can see how I apply a group validator on the `address` FormGroup. The validator implementation here is actually quite specific, validating that the user either provides both, `street` and `zipCode` or none of them:

```
const addressRequired = (control: AbstractControl) => {
  const street = control.get('street');
  const zipcode = control.get('zipCode');

  const values = [
    street.value,
    zipcode.value
  ];

  if(values.every(x => x === '') || values.every(x => x !== '')) {
    return null
  } else {
    return { addressIncomplete: true };
  }
}
```

Here's a running example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactiveforms-formgroup-validation?file=app/person-edit.component.ts

It's actually a stupid one just to showcase group validators. But you could easily generalize the validator by dynamically iterating the controls of a group s.t. it is applicable to every form group.

have fun

Answer (score 1):

You could take this generic validator.

```
// all-or-none.validator.ts

import { FormGroup, ValidationErrors, ValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';

export const allOrNoneRequiredValidator: ValidatorFn = (group: FormGroup): ValidationErrors | null => {
  const keys: string[] = Object.keys(group.controls);
  const valid: boolean = keys.every((key: string): boolean => !!group.controls[key].value) ||
    keys.every((key: string): boolean => !group.controls[key].value);
  return valid ? null : { allOrNoneRequired: true };
};
```

And use it as follows.

```
import { allOrNoneRequiredValidator } from '/path/to/all-or-none-required.validator';

...

this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
  firstName: '',
  lastName: '',
  address: this.formBuilder.group({
    street: '',
    zipCode: ''
  }, { validators: allOrNoneRequiredValidator })
});
```